# Printing code w/out comments

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, helper

I was given the assignment to print the code without the comments in it (all 3 kinds of comments: `/**/`, `//`, `/**/`) and this is what I have so far. Can someone please help me with what to do now? Thank you for your help.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class StripComments {

    /* this is the main method
    of my file
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new StripComments();
    }

    public StripComments() throws IOException {

        String line = "";

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("./src/StripComments.java"));
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {   // This tells me if there are more lines
            if(line.contains("//")) {
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println(line);
            line = sc.nextLine();
        }

        //Here is your code
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Comment: Basically, you've posted a program skeleton consisting only of the read loop.  All the logic required to solve the problem is missing.  So this looks like a "write my code for me" request, which is not the way StackOverflow works.

Comment: @JimGarrison I am not asking for someone to write the code for me I'm asking how should I approach this

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] and especially read [ask].  This question is off-topic and likely to get lots of downvotes and be put on hold.

Comment: Again, this is not how StackOverflow works.  Read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157)

Comment: *"all 3 kinds of comments: `/**/`, `//`, `/**/`"* The first and the third looks the same to me. Don't know why you even think Java has 3 kinds, given that Java Language Specification, section "[3.7. Comments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.7)" starts with: **There are *two* kinds of comments**

Comment: @JonKon please show us what you have tried and we can help you fix your errors. If you just need a pointer: read about [regex in java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). Then use `String.replaceAll("some regex", "")`

Comment: @LonelyNeuron so I'm trying to use (line.startsWith("/*") method but doesn't seem to work

Comment: if (line.startsWith("/*")){
                continue;
            }

Comment: there is /** that ends with */ and a /* that ends with */ @Andreas

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for answering follow-up questions to your question, but please instead [edit] your question to add any relevant information. Any question on Stack Overflow should make sense on its own so that other users finding this question in the future won't have to dig through all the comments to understand your post.

Comment: ok so now I added an if statement checking if the line contains "//" but when I run it it prints the  code until it finds a "//" @LonelyNeuron

Comment: @JonKon please refer to the comment I posted earlier. Read the article about regex in java. Then try to find a solution yourself using regex. If that fails post a new question with your attempt. I would also recommend deleting this question

Comment: @JonKon what is confusing you about that? Do you know what the `continue` command does in java? It skips to the next iteration in your loop. Therefore `line = ...` won't be called in this next iteration. So next turn we have the same value in `line`, so we skip again and so forth. You need to learn how to debug your code!

Comment: @JonKon Java has two comment types: `/* Traditional Comment */` that can span multiple lines, and `// End-Of-Line Comment` that lasts until the end of the line. --- There is no comment `/** fail /`. If you're thinking of a `/** Javadoc Comment */`, then it is just a traditional comment, as far as the *Java compiler* is concerned. --- There is no comment `/ fail */`. Don't know where you might have gotten that idea.

Comment: Remember, both types of comments can start *anywhere* in a line.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you're stuck on this problem!

```
line = sc.nextLine();
```

In that line of your program, you are reading the next line of the input file (i.e. the code). The first thing you will want to do is check if that line contains any of the operators you are looking for (namely // or /*).

Then, if it is // you will want to ignore everything after it. If it is /* you will want to ignore everything up to and including */.

Give it a shot and we can help you work through it

Comment: Please read [answer].  StackOverflow is NOT a discussion forum. Answers are supposed to be complete answers not "try this and let me know how it works".  It is not a dialog.  Also, the question is (at the moment) completely off-topic, and unanswerable.  If you need clarification, post a comment, which you cannot do until you have 50 rep.  Wait until then, do not abuse the system by posting comments as answers.

Comment: Thanks Jim, I actually hadn't seen that link before. As you can tell, I'm new here (as is the OP). While I read that, why don't you read this: https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/?cb=1

Comment: @JimGarrison  As a user who opened his account about an hour ago I think that you should read what Morcous Wahba has posted so other new users will not receive this "welcoming".

Comment: @MorcousWahba thank you for replying so positively to the rather "grumpy" criticism. And I have to agree, SO can be a little hostile at times. Try not to take it personal.

Comment: Answer is incomplete. It doesn't in any way address, or even warn about, the very real use case of a traditional `/*` comment ending on a different line.